# Creating dynamic bootstrap modals with php mysql and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

so I am working on a small ecommerce site and I've been stuck on this section of my site for quite a while now and can't really wrap my head around it.

I have divided the site into 3 columns with bootstrap's grid system, in the main section I have my featured products, however, I'd like everything to be dynamic, when I click on a modal with "View details" for the product the only code that works is the dynamic one, I'd like to know how to make it so that it pulls the data directly from my database, unfortunately out of frustration I deleted the little work I had done on it and can't show stick it on here so that anyone can correct it for me.

Could anyone please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could go about doing this. Here is an approach you could use:

- Get the id from data attribute of your product (make sure you load it into the html).
- Send a $.get request with jquery for this id to the server.
- Get the data needed from the db using this id.
- Render the data server side
- Return html
- In the callback function of your get request put the HTML into your bootstrap modal body.
- Show the modal to the user.

Comment: outdatted for SEO since SO would need to use a GET method to process the ID. Best bet is to use a Router and Controller for products, But it works so +1 !